# OpenID and desktop apps

Tags: openid, desktop

Looking at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID?hl=zh-TW#AuthProcess it uses a Web Application. Does this same process work for a desktop application that can make http(s) calls to do the same thing? The one obstacle I see is that the user is redirected to the site to login, like say google. How could I use this process for a desktop application instead of a website? If a person already has a FB or google ID I want them to be able to use that to log into my application. So there is a server piece of my application that needs to get this auth value to validate the login as well.

Every example you see if for web apps, but it would be nice if desktop apps could use this too (say video games that have a multiplayer to it) which this is what I'm trying to do. I don't want to track and store username/pw's if I can just use OpenID.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID is not the solution for your problem. Those two browser redirections (RP to OP and OP to RP) are mandatory for the OpenID Protocol, they are defined in the spec itself. 
But OAuth is the perfect solution for you.

- You don't have to store username/password
- You can avoid the browser redirections
- FB, Google, Twitter etc supports OAuth
- You have many other advantages for example, you can post user's games results on his facebook profile :)

So go for OAuth.